# Create a dynamic buddypress tab

Tags: php, wordpress, url, dynamic, buddypress

I am trying to create a dynamic buddypress tab linked to a dynamic url that looks like this `localhost/wordpress/slug/username`

this tab should appear to any user visiting another user's profile,, and when clicked it should redirect to the user visited and not the user visiting , I mean that the username at the end of my URL should be replaced by the username of the current profile visited

I am using the wp_redirect function to redirect the user to this url but the probleme is that i don't know how to write this url ?

I've tried to create a variable like so `$user = wp_get_current_user();` to includ it like so `wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user->display_name" );` but the final result is `http://localhost/wordpress2/slug/` i'm not even sure i should call this function current user so please someone help me

keep in mind that i'm writing my code in the function.php file in my theme folder

thats the code i added

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();




add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'create_tab3', 303 );
function create_tab3() {
    global $bp;
    bp_core_new_nav_item(
        array(
            'name'                    => 'my name',
            'slug'                    => 'slug', 
            'position'                => 21, 
            'default_subnav_slug'     => 'mySlug', // We add this submenu item below 
            'screen_function'         => 'redirect_user_to_tab3',
        )
    );

}
function redirect_user_to_tab3(){
    global $bp;
    wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress2/slug/$user->display_name" );
    exit;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `redirect_user_to_tab3` function doesn't have a `$user` variable in its scope, so `$user->display_name` is undefined.

You'll need to set `$user = wp_get_current_user();` within the function.

After that, [read the docs on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) as they're quite important in PHP.

Comment: ahhh thank you very much ,,, but it solved only half the probleme because now when i visite another user's profile and click on this tab from his profile it redirect me to my page (it change the username with mine) ,,, to be more clear lets say i'm user1 so when i click the tab from my profile i want this url   localhost/wordpress/slug/user1 ,,,, but if i clck the tab from user2's profile then i want this url  localhost/wordpress/slug/user2

Comment: i know i should call something different than `wp_get_current_user();` but i don't know what it is ,,, can you plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

someone answerd my question and told me to change the last function in my code like so

```
function redirect_user_to_tab3(){
    $url = site_url() . '/slug/' . bp_get_displayed_user_username();
    bp_core_redirect( $url );
}
```

and it worked fine ,,,, thanks to everyone that helped me